# How do I default a chart to a particular option in the range selector?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have this plot-

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattergl(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.Measure)), row = 1, col = 1)
    
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
            dict(count=1,
                 label="1m",
                 step="month",
                 stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=6,
                 label="6m",
                 step="month",
                 stepmode="backward")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)
```

I want to set it up so that when someone opens the dashboard, they 6 month range selector is already clicked. The underlying data goes back further than six months, and I want the dashboard to auto-select the six month option when the dashboard starts. Is that possible with range selector?